# remove multi linebreak present in key value pair . want single line after line break removal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

eg : input txt file

```
akey=avalue1,
     avalue2,
     avalue3

bkey=cvalue
```

here output I want in a list whose 2 elements will be

```
[akey=avalue1,avalue2,avalue3
bkey=cvalue]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not hard with a couple of regexps:

```
import re

data = """
akey=avalue1,
     avalue2,
     avalue3

bkey=cvalue
""".strip()

# Fold comma-newline-spaces to a single comma
data = re.sub(r",\n\s*", ",", data)
# Fold multiple newlines to one
data = re.sub(r"\n+", "\n", data)
print(data)
```

This outputs

```
akey=avalue1,avalue2,avalue3
bkey=cvalue
```